# Postgres - apply distinct on after order by in a performant way

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

Given the following table, I am trying to select distinct id values ordered by time. However, I want the order by time to be applied before the distinct, so the selected distinct row has always the lower `time` with that `id`. Is it possible to do so in a performant way - the table can have millions of rows and I don't want to do any operation that is not necessary - (such as first using subquery to order them by time and then applying distinct)

```
id  | time | value
1   | 0:00 |  'a'
1   | 2:00 |  'b'
2   | 4:00 |  'c'
2   | 3:00 |  'd'
2   | 2:00 |  'e'
3   | 5:00 |  'f'
3   | 3:00 |  'g'
```

Comment: show your expected  result  ..  too ..

Answer (score 3):

You want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, time asc;
```

In Postgres, this is typically the most performant solution.  You want an index on `(id, time)`.

You can also try:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select min(t2.time) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

With the same index, this should be competitive in performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working as I need, however, i think it does heap fetch for all rows before applying the distinct - is it possible to make it more effective to only do heap fetch for rows that are distinct?